# React-redux client-side only application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Is it possible to use react and redux to build a client-side only application? All data being used will also be stored locally.

Comment: Sure, react is a client side framework. I've never worked with the redux framework but it doesn't seem to have any server side dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux has no server-side dependencies. You can use redux and react as a client side or server-side as it can be built in an isomorphic fashion. If you remain client side the only obvious side-effect is that the data from the app will be lost once it is closed.